# Prestashop 1.6 default theme price

Tags: themes, prestashop

In prestashop 1.6 default theme i would like to change the price like on the photo. I tired the product.tpl file but its not working. I dont know why but i can not finde it the main file where i can modify the template. Is there any solution for this problem ? i should put simply just a br tag but i dont know what file should i use.

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zygf.jpg)

There has to be someone who know it. Should i try an another file ? or can i do it in the css ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using default-bootstrap theme you should look into themes/default-bootstrap/product-list.tpl

after changes remember about clearing the cache in Adv. Preferences -> Performance

Answer (score 0):

Two files shows products prices : `product.tpl and product-list.tpl` :
`product-list.tpl` is your product list on category page.
`product.tpl` shows only one product (product page)

You also have in `themes/default-bootstrap/css` files, like product.css and product-list.css

Before working on it (and as Krystian said), desactivate cache.

Prices have HTML useful classes in Prestashop :

```
.price
.product-price
```

This would help finding correct lines in template files.